# CSS/Bootstrap/HTML - Div with bottom border and padding...How to prevent extension of border on margin or padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with a bottom border and no matter whether I try padding left or right the border is extended to include bottom padding.

How do i restrict border to only the maximum length of the border, excluding padding or margin (left, right)?

**CSS**

```
div.row.banner div.links
     display: inline-block
     height: 40px
     margin: 0px
     border-bottom: 2px solid #5cdde0

div.row.banner div
     display: inline-block
     height: 25px
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 nopadding pull-right">
    <div class="links pull-right">
        <div class="active pull-left"><a href="">Test Link 1</a></div>
        <div class="active pull-left margin-left"><a href="">Test Link 2</a></div>
        <div class="active pull-left margin-left"><a href="">Text Link 3</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and the CSS you provided doesn't seem to apply to the HTML you provided(and is also formatted incorrectly).

Comment: I will make necessary modifications, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I have resolved the issue and will post my comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the border issue was due to my applying the border to the enclosing div of each of the anchor tag divs.

I revised the original below

```
div.row.banner div.links
     display: inline-block
     height: 40px
     margin: 0px
     border-bottom: 2px solid #5cdde0
```

To the following

```
div.row.banner div.links
     display: inline-block
     height: 40px
     margin: 0px

div.links div.active
     border-bottom: 2px solid #5cdde0
```

Thereby making border only apply to the inner divs not the container.